# Pass list as input parameter to predicate to calculate sum

Tags: parameters, prolog

As the title suggests, its baby steps for me in the world of `prolog`. I am passing a list of integers to a predicate. The list is then passed to another predicate which calculates and prints the resulting sum. Here is my code:

```
solve_dots(boardSize, boardRowVals) :-
    sum(boardRowVals,Sum),
    write(Sum).

sum([],0).  
sum([X|Tail],Sum):-
    sum(Tail,Temp),
    Sum is Temp + X.
```

Input:

```
?- solve_dots(3,[0,2,1]).
```

Output is always `false` in this case. However if I run the code below, it works fine:

```
findsum(L) :-
    sum(L,Sum),
    write(Sum).

sum([],0).
sum([X|Tail],Sum):-
    sum(Tail,Temp),
    Sum is Temp + X.
```

I am not able to figure out what exactly wrong is done with my input that makes it go false?

Comment: Variables in Prolog start with either an upper case letter or an underscore. `boardSize` and `boardRowVals` are *atoms*. Atoms don't unify with integers or lists. Thus, your query doesn't unify with the head of the single clause for the `solve_dots/2` predicate.

Comment: Woah! Can you provide this in answer so I can mark it?

Comment: As a beginner, do not use `write/1`. Instead, you can enter `sum([1,3,4], Sum).` directly at the toplevel.